# How to update an array in Parse from Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

My Parse class is Groups.

In that class I have many columns including createdBy: String and GroupMembersList: Array

For one row, I have the following value:

```
GroupMembersList = ["Arun", "Daniel", "Jo"]
```

Now how can I `add` `remove` and `update` the members of this group from my  swift code?

So far  I know this:

```
var query:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Groups")
query.whereKey("CreatedBy", equalTo: "Arun")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a property to your group and deal with it like with usual array:

```
extension Group {
    var membersList: [String] {
        get {
            if let x = self["GroupMembersList"] as? [String] { return x }
            return []
        }
        set(val) {
            self["GroupMembersList"] = val
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**: it's possible to create custom `PFObject` subclasses with Parse ([docs](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#objects-subclasses)):

```
class Group: PFObject, PFSubclassing {
    static func parseClassName() -> String {
        return "Group"
    }

    var membersList: [String] {
        get {
            if let x = self["GroupMembersList"] as? [String] { return x }
            return []
        }
        set(val) {
            self["GroupMembersList"] = val
        }
    }
}
```

In `AppDelegete` make this before `Parse.setApplicationId`:

```
Group.registerSubclass()
```

After that you can use your subclass like this:

```
let group = Group(objectId: "<group_id>")
group.membersList = ["some", "members", "here"]
let first = group.membersList[0]
group.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success, error) in
    if (success) {
        // The object has been saved.
    } else {
        // There was a problem, check error.description
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont understand. can u explain?

Comment: I still dont understand how can I update this new group to Parse

Comment: As any `PFObject`: using `.saveInBackground` or `.saveInBackgroundWithBlock` method

Comment: am sorry, i still dont get you. can you give the code where I can `.saveInBackground` the updated Array

Comment: @AAA added `saveInBackground` example to answer